# I don't want to update input type file manually

Tags: php

**I wants to update my file which i had inserted in database when i am updating it updated but when i am not updating its updated null value so i want that value which i had inserted i don't want to update manually any Solution for this**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>

<?php
include('header1.php');

?>
<!-- Javascript -->

  </head>
  <body >


    <?php
      include('sidenav.php');
      ?>

 <div id="page-wrapper" >
 <div id="page-inner">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">



<?php
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
 echo"<h2>Update Product</h2>";
 }
 else
 {
    echo"<h2>Add Product</h2>";
 }   
?>    

            </div>
            </div>
             <!-- /. ROW  -->
             <hr />
             <div class="row"> 

                  <?php 

                   include('config.php');
                    if(isset($_GET['id']))
                    {
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {


                            echo "working"; 
                                $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                                $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                                $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                                $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"]; 

                                if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                                {
                                    if($fileSize<=200)
                                { 
                                    $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                    $newFileName=$random.$fileName;
                                    $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;
                                    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                                {
                                    echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                                }
                            }
                                else
                                {
                                        return false;
                                        echo "You can only upload a pdf doc file.";
                                }  

                            }   



                            $cat=$_POST['catnm'];
                            $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                            $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

                             $updates = $_POST['downld'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                            //$downld=$_POST['downld'];
                            $date=$_POST['date'];
                            $query3=mysql_query("update addproduct set catnm='$cat', prodnm='$prodnm',prod_dtl='$prod_dtl'
                            ,pdf='$uploadPath',downld='$updates',date='$date' where id='$id'");
                                if($query3)
                                {
                                    header('location:addProduct.php');
                                }
                         }
                            $query1=mysql_query("select * from addproduct where id='$id'");
                            $query4=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
                            //echo "<pre>";
                            //print_r($query4);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {

                                echo"Upload Only PDf File"; 
                                $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                                $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                                $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                                $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"];  

                        if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                        {
                            if($fileSize<=200){

                        //New file name
                                $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                $newFileName=$random.$fileName;

                        //File upload path
                                $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;

                        //function for upload file

                                if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                                {
                                    echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                                }
                            }
                                else
                                {
                                        return false;
                                        echo "You can only upload a pdf file.";
                                }  


                                    echo "here downld";
                                    $updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

                                    $catnm=$_POST['catnm'];
                                    $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                                    $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

                                    //$updates=$_POST['downld'];
                                    $date=$_POST['date'];

                                    $query=("insert into addproduct(catnm,prodnm,prod_dtl,pdf,downld,date)
                                    values('$catnm','$prodnm','$prod_dtl','$uploadPath','$updates','$date')");
                                    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

                                    if($result)
                                    {
                                        header('location:addProduct.php');
                                    }
                                }

                        }
                        }


                  ?>

       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">      
                <div class="panel-body">            
       <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="myform" >
                <br/>

                <label>Select Category:</label>      
                <div class="form-group">
                  <?php

                        include('config.php');
                        $query1=mysql_query("select catnm from addcategory");
                        ?>
                        <select class=form-control m-b-10 name=catnm id=catnm >
                        <?php
                         echo"<option>---Select---</option required>";
                        while($query=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
                        {

                            $selectedCat = '';
                            if($query[catnm] == $query4['catnm'])
                            {
                                $selectedCat = "selected";
                            }

                             echo "<option value='$query[catnm]' $selectedCat >$query[catnm]</option>"; 
                        }

                    ?>                                    
                    </select>



            <br/>                 
           <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prodnm" placeholder="Product Name" name="prodnm" required value="<?php if(isset($query4['prodnm'])){echo $query4['prodnm'];}?>"/>
           </div>

         <div class="form-group">       
        <textarea class="form-control" id="catdtl" name="prod_dtl" placeholder="Product Detail" "rows="10" cols="62" required><?php if(isset($query4['prod_dtl'])){echo $query4['prod_dtl'];} ?></textarea>
         </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">PDF File</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" accept="application/pdf" name="filepdf" >  
        file : <?php if(isset($query4['pdf'])){
        echo $query4['pdf'];} ?>                        
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="updates" 
        <?php  if(isset($query4['downld'])) { if($query4['downld'] == 'Yes') echo "checked='checked'"; echo $query4['downld'];} 
        ?> /> Is Downloadable <br />
        </label>
        </div>





 <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Upload" name="date" value="<?php 

if(isset($query4['date'])){echo $query4['date'];}?>"id="datepicker-7">
             <div style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:40px;width:650px;">


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="<?php 

if(isset($_GET['id'])){$id = $_GET['id'];echo"Update";}else{echo"Submit";}?>"/>


 <input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="window.location='index.php'"/>                         



         <hr/>

         </form>



 </div>
                 <!-- /. ROW  -->
    </div>
             <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
            </div>
         <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please apply another condition after this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>

<?php
include('header1.php');

?>
<!-- Javascript -->

  </head>
  <body >


    <?php
      include('sidenav.php');
      ?>

 <div id="page-wrapper" >
 <div id="page-inner">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">



<?php
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
 echo"<h2>Update Product</h2>";
 }
 else
 {
    echo"<h2>Add Product</h2>";
 }   
?>    

            </div>
            </div>
             <!-- /. ROW  -->
             <hr />
             <div class="row"> 

                  <?php 

                   include('config.php');
                    if(isset($_GET['id']))
                    {
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {

                            echo "working"; 
                                $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                                $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                                $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                                $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"]; 

                                if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                                {
                                    if($fileSize<=200)
                                { 
                                    $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                    $newFileName=$random.$fileName;
                                    $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;
                                    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                                {
                                    echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                                }
                            }
                                else
                                {
                                        return false;
                                        echo "You can only upload a pdf doc file.";
                                }  

                            }   



                            $cat=$_POST['catnm'];
                            $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                            $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

                             $updates = $_POST['downld'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                            //$downld=$_POST['downld'];
                            $date=$_POST['date'];
                             if(isset($_POST['filepdf']) && $_POST['filepdf']!=='') {  //if filepdf is not null
                                 $query3=mysql_query("update addproduct set catnm='$cat', prodnm='$prodnm',prod_dtl='$prod_dtl'
                            ,pdf='$uploadPath',downld='$updates',date='$date' where id='$id'");
                             } else {  //if filepdf is null
                                $query3=mysql_query("update addproduct set catnm='$cat', prodnm='$prodnm',prod_dtl='$prod_dtl'
                            ,downld='$updates',date='$date' where id='$id'");
                             }
                                if($query3)
                                {
                                    header('location:addProduct.php');
                                }
                         }
                            $query1=mysql_query("select * from addproduct where id='$id'");
                            $query4=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
                            //echo "<pre>";
                            //print_r($query4);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {

                                echo"Upload Only PDf File"; 
                                $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                                $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                                $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                                $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"];  

                        if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                        {
                            if($fileSize<=200){

                        //New file name
                                $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                $newFileName=$random.$fileName;

                        //File upload path
                                $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;

                        //function for upload file

                                if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                                {
                                    echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                                }
                            }
                                else
                                {
                                        return false;
                                        echo "You can only upload a pdf file.";
                                }  


                                    echo "here downld";
                                    $updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

                                    $catnm=$_POST['catnm'];
                                    $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                                    $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

                                    //$updates=$_POST['downld'];
                                    $date=$_POST['date'];

                                    $query=("insert into addproduct(catnm,prodnm,prod_dtl,pdf,downld,date)
                                    values('$catnm','$prodnm','$prod_dtl','$uploadPath','$updates','$date')");
                                    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

                                    if($result)
                                    {
                                        header('location:addProduct.php');
                                    }
                                }

                        }
                        }


                  ?>

       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">      
                <div class="panel-body">            
       <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="myform" >
                <br/>

                <label>Select Category:</label>      
                <div class="form-group">
                  <?php

                        include('config.php');
                        $query1=mysql_query("select catnm from addcategory");
                        ?>
                        <select class=form-control m-b-10 name=catnm id=catnm >
                        <?php
                         echo"<option>---Select---</option required>";
                        while($query=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
                        {

                            $selectedCat = '';
                            if($query[catnm] == $query4['catnm'])
                            {
                                $selectedCat = "selected";
                            }

                             echo "<option value='$query[catnm]' $selectedCat >$query[catnm]</option>"; 
                        }

                    ?>                                    
                    </select>



            <br/>                 
           <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prodnm" placeholder="Product Name" name="prodnm" required value="<?php if(isset($query4['prodnm'])){echo $query4['prodnm'];}?>"/>
           </div>

         <div class="form-group">       
        <textarea class="form-control" id="catdtl" name="prod_dtl" placeholder="Product Detail" "rows="10" cols="62" required><?php if(isset($query4['prod_dtl'])){echo $query4['prod_dtl'];} ?></textarea>
         </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">PDF File</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" accept="application/pdf" name="filepdf" >  
        file : <?php if(isset($query4['pdf'])){
        echo $query4['pdf'];} ?>                        
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="updates" 
        <?php  if(isset($query4['downld'])) { if($query4['downld'] == 'Yes') echo "checked='checked'"; echo $query4['downld'];} 
        ?> /> Is Downloadable <br />
        </label>
        </div>





 <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Upload" name="date" value="<?php 

if(isset($query4['date'])){echo $query4['date'];}?>"id="datepicker-7">
             <div style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:40px;width:650px;">


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="<?php 

if(isset($_GET['id'])){$id = $_GET['id'];echo"Update";}else{echo"Submit";}?>"/>


 <input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="window.location='index.php'"/>                         



         <hr/>

         </form>



 </div>
                 <!-- /. ROW  -->
    </div>
             <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
            </div>
         <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Err... spot the difference...?!

Comment: Its not working ...null value update in database when click on update button.

Comment: Now filepdf  is only updating when filepdf is not null.

Comment: when define value and variable in else part it update pdf file but when send empty it send null value what to do...??